# Can anyone plz tell me why in this code the button is not clickable, and how to make it clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, submit

I have two text input fields in html and one button. first will take id and second will take password, clicking on button will either display a div saying welcome or a paragraph asking for correct login credentials. the id and password are hard-coded.
Thing is that the submit button is not clickable at all. I don't know what is causing this failure, plz help.

```
<input type="text" class="id" style="margin-top:10px">

<input type="text" class="pass" style="margin-top:10px">

<button class="enter" style="margin-top:6px; padding:6px; background:orange;">Enter</button>

<p class="loginMsg"></p>


<script>
  const idvalue ="Superhero";
  const passvalue ="Superzero";
  const id = document.querySelector(".id");
  const pass = document.querySelector(".pass");
  const enter = document.querySelector(".enter");
  const para = document.querySelector(".loginMsg");
  enter.onclick = function() {
    let myid = id.value;
    let mypass = pass.value;
    if(myid==idvalue && mypass==passvalue) {
      let panel = document.createElement("div");
      let msgpara = document.createElement("p");
      msgpara.textContent="Welcome back "+idvalue;
      let btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.textContent = "OK";
      panel.appendChild(msgpara);
      panel.appendChild(btn);
      html.appendChild(panel);
      btn.onclick = function(){
        panel.parentNode.removeChild(panel);
      };

    };
    else {
      para.textContent = "Please enter correct id and password.";
    };
  };


</script>
```

Comment: install a linter on your IDE

Answer (score 0):

Check your code on line 33, you added a semicolon before the else in your if-else statement

```
if{
   ...};
      else{
      };
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/gfL8jwhq/ for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes due to semicolon(;) after if() condition creating the issue remove it, and it will work properly

```
enter.onclick = function() {
    let myid = id.value;
    let mypass = pass.value;
    if(myid==idvalue && mypass==passvalue) {
      let panel = document.createElement("div");
      let msgpara = document.createElement("p");
      msgpara.textContent="Welcome back "+idvalue;
      let btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.textContent = "OK";
      panel.appendChild(msgpara);
      panel.appendChild(btn);
      html.appendChild(panel);
      btn.onclick = function(){
        panel.parentNode.removeChild(panel);
      };

    } else {
      para.textContent = "Please enter correct id and password.";
    };
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Beside this I forgot to define the html element, that was also causing the panel to not display. thanks for help.